# How to extend a java class extending a typed-parameter of another class in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, oop, inheritance, parameterized-types

Suppose I have a Java class A that extends a parameterized type of class B (parameterized for C):

```
public class A extends B <C> {
    public A (Class<? extends C > data) {
        super((Class<C>) data);
    }
}
```

Now lets say I have a different Scala class, D, that wishes to extend class A.

```
class D extends A {
    .... }
```

Whatever I try to pass to class D (in the declaration itself, or in the Ctor below it, or by calling the base Ctor via super) -  I still get a compilation error:

> "unspecified value parameters: class [ _ < C ]"

Could not find the correct way to define my Scala class D.

for any case, real code is (using com.fasterxml.jackson):

```
public class DateTimeDeserializer extends          
    JodaDeserializerBase<ReadableInstant>      {
        public DateTimeDeserializer(Class<? extends ReadableInstant> cls) {
            super((Class<ReadableInstant>)cls);
    }
...
}
```

and the scala:

```
class CustomDateTimeDeserializer extends DateTimeDeserializer {}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You need to adjust the variance of the type parameter I guess (`+C`).

Answer (score 1):

-- SOLVED --

Discovered that the way to do it in Scala is using "classOf" (in java it is .class) as follows:

```
class A() extends B(classOf[C]) {}
```

or in my code:

```
class CustomDateTimeDeserializer() extends DateTimeDeserializer(classOf[DateTime]) {
 ...
}
```